# Is there a way for Apache to silently ignore unrecognized .htaccess directives?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zeus

I'm in the unfortunate position of having an Apache staging server combined with a Zeus web server. (Not my choice).

I'd like to be able to include a Zeus-specific directive in the .htaccess file (e.g. ContentCompressionEnabled) and, if possible,  include the Apache equivalent (AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE) in the same file too.

Is there a way of doing this which doesn't involve separate .htaccess files for Zeus and Apache?

Answer (score 3):

Only in 2.4, where there is an Nonfatal option to AllowOverride.

Comment: Sadly the staging server is Windows XP - no offical Apache binaries for 2.4 yet (that I can find) - but I will look into doing this.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you can use **httpd.conf** file do this configuration for all requests. **.htaccess** file configurations effect only requests to where the file located.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your answer. The primary problem is getting Apache to ignore Zeus-specific contents in an .htaccess file so that the same file can be used on the staging (Apache 2.x) and Zeus web servers.

Answer (score 1):

You could put any Apache only directives into either Apache's main `httpd.conf` file, or the sites vhost config file - along with `AllowOverride None`.

This would mean that Apache would get all it's config info from there and ignore any `.htaccess` files completely.

You could then place anything you wanted in the .htaccess files, including all the Zeus config you need - and Zeus would be configured only from there - thus separating the two configs.